# setPercent function is printing garbage data

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop

Just started working with OOP and it hasnt been very fun. im writing a program where the user chooses 3options from a menu (1. print all 2. change score 3. quit) Im stuck on the print all function. I want to print out 3 things the name of each student their percent and their scores(the scores and names are read in from a file). Problem is percent keeps printing out garbage data. So i did some debugging and i found out that when i read in the scores of each student its reading in extra values of garbage data which is ruining the calculation. I've tried to fix it but havent had any luck. All help and tips are appreciated below is the code and i will also post the IMG of my debugging and the garbage data i found being stored in scores[i].

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
private: 
    string name;
    int *scores;
    int numstu;
    int numscores;
    int maxscore;
    double percent;

public:
    //Mutator
    void setName(string inName) {name = inName;}
    void setNumstu(int iNum) {numstu = iNum;}
    void setNumscores(int sNum) {numscores = sNum;}
    void setMaxscore(int mNum) {maxscore = mNum;}
    void setScores(int *list);
    void setPercent ();

    //Accessor
    string getName () const {return name;}
    int getNumScores () const {return numscores;}
    int getNumStu () const {return numstu;}
    int getMaxScore () const {return maxscore;}
    double getPercent () const {return percent;}
    int *getScoreslist () const {return scores;}

    //constructor
    //Student();
};


void Student::setScores(int *list)
{
    scores = new int[numscores];
    for (int i = 0; i < numscores; i++)
    {
        scores[i] = list[i];
    }
};

void Student::setPercent() 
{   
    double sum = 0;
    //debugging shows scores is being filled with garbage data
    for (int i = 0; i < numscores; i++)
    {
        cout << scores[i] << endl;
    } 

    for(int i = 0; i < numscores; i++)
    {   
        sum = sum + scores[i];
    }
    //cout << sum;
    percent = (sum/maxscore) * 100.0;
    sum = 0;

    //cout << percent;
};


Student *fillArr(int &numstu, int &numscores, int &maxscore);
void printAll(Student *stuArr, int numstu, int numscores);

int main() 
{

    int numstu;
    int numscores;
    int maxscore;
    int choice;


    Student *stuArr;
    stuArr = fillArr(numstu, numscores, maxscore);
    if(stuArr == 0)
    {
        cout << "Error." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Menu:" << endl;
    cout << "1. Print All" << endl;
    cout << "2. Change Score" << endl;
    cout << "3. Quit" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    do 
    {
        if(choice == 1)
        {
            printAll(stuArr, numstu, numscores);
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            cout << "Change Score" << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            cout << "Good Bye" << endl;
            exit(100);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "That is not a valid option." << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    } while (choice !=1 && choice !=2 && choice != 3); 

    return 0;
};

Student *fillArr(int &numstu, int &numscores, int &maxscore)
{
    //Opening file and checking if it exists
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("grades.txt");
    if(!infile)
    {
        cout << "Error Opening file\n";
        return 0;
    }
    string temp;

    //Reding in number of students, number of scores, and maximum score
    infile >> numstu >> numscores >> maxscore;

    //Dynamically Allocating new memory for each student 
    Student *newStu = new Student[numstu];
    infile.ignore();

    for (int i = 0; i < numstu; i++)
    {
        getline(infile, temp);
        newStu[i].setName(temp);
        newStu[i].setMaxscore(maxscore);
        newStu[i].setNumscores(numstu);

        int *list = new int[numscores];

        for (int z = 0; z < numscores; z++)
        {
            infile >> list[z];      
        };

        newStu[i].setScores(list);

        infile.ignore();    
    };


    return newStu;
    infile.close();
};

void printAll(Student *stuArr, int numstu, int numscores)
{
    cout << "Name\t" << "\tGrade\t" << "\tScores\t" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < numstu; i++)
    {
        //calling setpercent mutator
        stuArr[i].setPercent();
        cout << setprecision(1) << fixed << left;

        //printing out each name and percent of each student 
        cout << setw(20) << stuArr[i].getName() << setw(19) << stuArr[i].getPercent() << setw(20);

        printing out the scores of each student works correctly here for some odd reason
        const int *ptr = stuArr[i].getScoreslist();
        for (int z = 0; z < numscores; z++)
        {
            cout << left;
            cout << setw(4) << ptr[z];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};
```

[image: garbage data being read in(not sure but thats my assumption) also you can see next to it that when i print out the scores in the printAll fucntion they are being printed normally with no garbage data]

Comment: Soo.. where is the constructor? and you definitely aren't following the rule of 3

Comment: have you tried to print out the value of `maxscore` as you're debugging?

Comment: rule of 3? and yes maxscore is being read in correctly.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going wrong without seeing the input file. It looks like your scores array is longer than the number of scores you're reading in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug in this line: newStu[i].setNumscores(numstu); it should be newStu[i].setNumscores(numscores); instead